# Почему возникает ошибка 'tuple' object is not callable (line33), pygame

Tags: python, pip, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
RES=800
SIZE=600

# размер дисплея

display = pygame.display.set_mode((RES , SIZE))

# название игры
pygame.display.set_caption("test game")

# иконка игры
icon = pygame.image.load("icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# размер персонажа
usr_shirina = 60
usr_visota = 100
usr_x = RES // 3
usr_y = SIZE - usr_visota - 100

# анимация прыжка
anim_jump = False
jump_counter = 30

# кактусы
cactus_height = 70
cactus_widht = 20
cactus_x = RES - 50
cactus_y = SIZE - RES - 100

def cactus_draw():
    global  cactus_x , cactus_y , cactus_height , cactus_widht

    if cactus_x >= -cactus_widht:
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(162, 207, 10) (cactus_y , cactus_x, cactus_widht , cactus_height))
        cactus_x -= 4
    else:
        cactus_x = RES - 50



# время
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#игровой цикл
def run_game():
    game = True

# бесконечный цикл
while run_game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    land = pygame.image.load("land1.png")

    # клавиши
    keys =  pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        anim_jump = True

    # прыжок
    def jump():
        global usr_y, anim_jump, jump_counter
        if jump_counter >= -30:
            usr_y -= jump_counter / 2.5
            jump_counter -= 1
        else:
            jump_counter = 30
            anim_jump = False


    if anim_jump:
        jump()



    # цвет дисплея
    display.blit(land , (0,0))
    cactus_draw()
    
    # цвет персонажа
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (166,225,40), (usr_x , usr_y , usr_visota , usr_shirina))
    
    # чтобы цвет отображался
    pygame.display.update()
    
    # анимация
    clock.tick(60)


run_game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом месте пропущена запятая:

```
pygame.draw.rect(display,(162, 207, 10) (cactus_y , cactus_x, cactus_widht , cactus_height))
```

Должно быть:

```
pygame.draw.rect(display,(162, 207, 10), (cactus_y , cactus_x, cactus_widht , cactus_height))
```